# Internet not working when using Static IP. No current solutions working

Tags: networking, configuration

`Ifconfig` returns the following:

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.1.39  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fefa:258e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 08:00:27:fa:25:8e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 20  bytes 1368 (1.3 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

My `etc/network/interfaces` looks like this:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.39
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
```

`Route -n` returns the following:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
```

I am using the following dns:

```
domain **
search **
nameserver 172.139.62.5
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

*(Stars hiding my local DNS which I rather not have public)*

Using a non-static IP does work. 
I am running Linux in a VM.

Comment: A static IP does not work everywhere. The local infra-structure might actually prevent you from doing that, or from you having NAT to the outside.   It is much wiser to define in the DHCP server that your actual MAC has a fixed IP address.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I am running multiple VMs, and I want to communicate between them. From what I understand this is much easier with a static IP on all of them.

Comment: When you set the interface to DHCP what do the commands you listed return? Chances are your DHCP is doing something that you aren't setting manually.

Comment: When you use a static IP, can you ping the gateway? Can you ping other VMs? Is the VM using bridged networking, or does it use networking such as NAT or host-only that uses the host as the gateway?

Comment: Is your gateway really `192.168.1.1` or did you guess that?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick It is not working I am getting "From 192.168.1.39 icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable"

Comment: @roaima I bought a book to learn how to use linux, this is what it recommended to set it as, but it didn't explain why.

Comment: @MitchelJager, you need to use addresses that match what is on your actual network.  `192.168.1.1` is a commonly used SOHO gateway address, but far from universal.  Compare what the results of `ifconfig` and `route -n` are when the address is assigned via DHCP.

Comment: The `gateway` address must be set to match the internal address of your router.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that the gateway address you are using, `192.168.1.1` does not match the address of your router. If you are using static IP addressing the details much match your network or it cannot work.

Start with the IP address of your router. It might be 192.168.1.254. It might be 10.11.12.13. It could be something else entirely.

You then need the netmask, again from your router configuration, which will either be 24 or something like 255.255.255.0.

For every 255 in the netmask you need to copy through the corresponding numbers from your router's IP address. So three lots of 255 would mean you copy through the first three groups of numbers. (If you have only a single number netmask such as 24, divide it by 8, and the result gives you the count of the numbers you must copy through.) Finally, you need to assign unused values so that you end up with four groups of numbers.

Assume your router is 10.1.1.254 and your netmask is 255.255.0.0. Then you'd copy through 10.1 and come up with the remaining two numbers in the range 1-254. The result is your IP address, eg 10.1.44.66, but do not use a number group that's already in use!

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, but it's a bit difficult to understand as someone with limited knowledge. The "Default Gateway" I am getting is 172.139.62.254, I have entered this, but this has not yet worked. The "subnet mask" I am getting is 255.255.255.0, as I had already entered. I am not quite ure what I do with this. The IP of my router is 172.139.62.157.

Comment: @MitchelJager unless you have an unusual network your router will be your default gateway. Are you sure your router's address really is 172.139.62.157 and not 172.139.62.254? The .157 feels more like an address assigned to your client.

Comment: @MitchelJager I see you say that your Windows VMs work with static addresses. Why not apply the same (or similar) values to your Linux VM?

Comment: OP appears to be using VirtualBox (MAC address 08:00:27:...). We can give better advice if he identifies what kind of networking (bridged, NAT, host-only) his Linux VM is using - the answer will determine whether the gateway is a virtual router offered by VB or a real router on the OP's network.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I'm using NAT, but I couild swap to bridged if that makes a change.

Comment: @roaima it says "Ethernet adapter Ethernet: IPv4 Address 172.139.62.157, Default gateway: 172.139.62.254"

Comment: @roaima I seme to be mistaken, the internet is my windows VM does NOT work either.

Comment: VB's NAT, last I checked, won't let guests talk to each other directly, so there's no advantage to choosing a static address (unless you just want to disable the DHCP client for efficiency). If you use bridged networking, your guests can talk to each other; you'll need to either use a DHCP server outside of your host system (often provided by a router), or assign static addresses based on the network of the router that is outside of your host system.

Comment: @roaima I managed to get it working! It turned out I was using the wrong address all along. Thank you!